# Register FileObserver after mounting SD card

Tags: android, file, android-intent, fileobserver

In my application I need to increase the count of photos when one is captured. So I set a `FileObserver` for the `DCIM directory`. It watches for captured photos.

However, this `FileObserver` stops watching when I unmount my SD card because the `DCIM directory` is no longer present. When I mount the SD card, I tried to register the `FileObserver` once again after I got `android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE` intent. But the `FileObserver` is not getting registered.

My questions are:

1. Is there any other way to make the `FileObserver` watch after mounting the SD card?
2. In some devices (HTC) I don't get any intents after I mount the SD card. What method can I use in that case?
3. Is there any other method to listen to the Photo taken by user in his built in soft button camera. I don't want to built my own camera.

   ```
   fo = new FileObserver(path.toString(),
                       FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE) {

                   @Override
                   public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
                       Log.d("yes", "event "+ event);
                       Log.d("operator",
                               "out side if"
                                       + Phototaken
                                       + externalStorageState
                                               .equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED));
                       if (Phototaken == 0 && event == 8){
                           String st = timeStamp();
                           Log.d("operator", "in event " + Phototaken);
                           Log.d("operator", "lat: " + MainService.lat
                                   + " " + "lng: " + MainService.lng + " "
                                   + "location: " + MainService.addre
                                   + " " + "time: " + st);
                           ptd.insert(st, String.valueOf(MainService.lat),
                                   String.valueOf(MainService.lng),
                                   MainService.addre);
                       }

                   }
               };
               fo.startWatching();
   ```

Comment: Based on [your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132796/161198) I made some minor edits. Check to see if they are correct. And please properly format your code. If it looks right, you're more likely to keep other people's attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a new `BroadcastReceiver` to watch for SD mount/unmount events. Then, on a mount event, tell your `FileObserver` to start watching again the `DCIM` directory.

You need to specify intent filters to watch for the events you want:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED);
```

[This snippet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) from the official API reference shows how to monitor the state of the external storage.